# Going up a directory in babashka

Tags: clojure, scripting, babashka

I am trying to traverse the fp in `babashka`, and have found that running `(shell "cd ..")` in my script `bb-test` causes an error:

```
----- Error --------------------------------------------------------------------
Type:     java.io.IOException
Message:  Cannot run program "cd": error=2, No such file or directory
Location: /home/jack/Documents/clojure/leingit/./bb-test:120:1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `cd` is a shell internal.  It can not be called like a regular program. You can run it via `sh -c 'cd ..'`, but that is just a no-op. It would help if you could shed light on why you want to change the cwd or what you plan to do in the next steps.

Comment: @cfrick, I want to do some git commands in a newly made directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the working directory in babashka (it is a limitation that comes from being a JVM-derived environment). But you can spawn new processes in other directories:

```clj
(require '[babashka.process :refer [shell]])

(shell {:dir ".."} "whatever")
```

Answer (score 1):

`cd` is shell built-in; you can not call it outside a shell.  So what
you want to do instead is run your command with a changed "current
working directory".  This can be done in [`sh` with the `:dir`
option](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.shell/sh).  E.g.

```clj
(-> (shell/sh "ls" :dir "/etc") :out)
```

This will list the content of `/etc` from wherever you are calling your
script.

(as mentioned in the comments of the question, this is about calling git
commands: git also allows for changing its root via the `GIT_WORK_TREE`
env-var, which could be changed via the `:env` option from `sh`, but
changing the cwd is more straightforward)